# Deploying Multiple Contracts at the same address using hardhat

Tags: hardhat

Consider I have two contracts A & B. B inherits A.

Now i want to deploy using hardhat and at the same address.

How can i do?

Example of what i want to do, but since in the new hardhat version there is no function as getContractfactory

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    console.log('Deploying contracts with the account: ' + deployer.address);

    // Deploy First
    const First = await ethers.getContractFactory('FirstContract');
    const first = await First.deploy();

    // Deploy Second
    const Second = await ethers.getContractFactory('SecondContract');
    const second = await Second.deploy(first.address);

    console.log( "First: " + first.address );
    console.log( "Second: " + second.address ); 
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit())
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
})
```

Instead there is direct

```
  const contractEvents = await hre.ethers.deployContract("ContractEvents");

  await contractEvents.waitForDeployment();
  console.log(`Contract deployed at ${contractEvents.target}`);
```

Which is working properly to deploy a single contract, but i want to deploy another contract at the same deployed address i.e the contractEvents.target, any suggestions how can i do?
I have read through other articles but they are quiet old and many of the functions couldnt be found like deployContractFactory (error shown by using the first code)

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, i just need to only one contract i.e deploy the most derived child contract, in its ABI all of the classes functions would be available to use.

Comment: Close the question